# Dynamically add options from array to jquery multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am trying to append items to a multi-select with checkboxes. The list is prepared but with no checkboxes. this is the scenario
I have several category lists like dairy, vegetables and so on. Selected items from these lists are stored in an array. To get confirmation from the user, the selected items are displayed in another list that needs to be created dynamically similar to the one below. However, the list is prepared as in the second image.
This is the code

```
$.each(arr1, function(index, value){         
  $("#mySelect").append($("<option>",{
    value: value,
    text: value
  }));
});

$('mySelect').multipleSelect({
  isOpen: true,
  keepOpen: true
});
```

Select with check boxes

[image]

multi select

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, I've never used multi-select. But if you wait to instantiate the plugin until the content is there it may work.

```
$.each(arr1, function(index, value){         
  $("#mySelect").append($("<option>",{
    value: value,
    text: value
  }));

  if (index == arr1.length-1) {
    $('mySelect').multipleSelect({
      isOpen: true,
      keepOpen: true
    });
  }
});
```